# Disable KDE Launcher - Browser history integration

Tags: kde, plasma

Whenever I search for something in KDE's Kickoff Application launcher, it also search in my browser history (both Firefox and Chromium).

I already disabled Nepomuk and selected "do not remember" under System Settings - Activities - Privacy. But it still shows my browser history.

How can i disable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like there's any way to do it in the UI.

But, you can edit the /usr/share/kde4/services/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop file.

```
kdesudo kate /usr/share/kde4/services/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop
```

Find this line:

```
X-KDE-PluginInfo-EnabledByDefault=true
```

and change it to:

```
X-KDE-PluginInfo-EnabledByDefault=false
```

You'll have to restart plasma for it to take effect:

```
kquitapp plasma-desktop
plasma-desktop
```

I'm not sure if this change will persist when KDE is updated, though.  My recommendation would be to instead avoid all this trouble by just using the lancelot application launcher (package name is `plasma-widget-lancelot`).  I prefer it to kickoff, and it has a UI that allows you to disable the bookmarks runner for the search bar.

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem when upgrading from openSUSE 12.2 to openSUSE 13.1 and with your answer as a starting point, I found a solution that satisfies me (see my answer).

Answer (score 7):

<strike>For KDE 4:

Copy */usr/share/kde4/services/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop*

→ *~/.kde/share/kde4/services/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop*</strike>

For KDE 5:
Copy */usr/share/kservices5/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop*
→ *~/.local/share/kservices5/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop*

Replace a line `X-KDE-PluginInfo-EnabledByDefault=false`.

**Relogin.**

---

Shorthand for the above:

```bsh
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/kservices5
sed 's/EnabledByDefault=true/EnabledByDefault=false/' \
    /usr/share/kservices5/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop \
    > ~/.local/share/kservices5/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop
```

Comment: After a reboot it seemed to work.

Comment: FWIW you don't need to logout/login, nor reboot. Restarting plasmashell is sufficient: `kbuildsycoca5 && timeout 5 kquitapp5 plasmashell && plasmashell`

Comment: or short `cp /usr/share/kservices5/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop ~/.local/share/kservices5/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop && kate ~/.local/share/kservices5/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop` and then @Sparhawk's command using Alt + F2

Answer (score 5):

(Inspired by user2798869's answer.) Another option is to create a file /home/(username)/.kde/share/kde4/services/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop with contents

```
X-KDE-PluginInfo-EnabledByDefault=false
```

This has the advantage over modifying the file in /usr/share/kde4/ that it will certainly persist software updates, and even OS reinstall if you have a separate home partition.

(I have tested this on openSUSE 13.1, where the file path is /home/(username)/.kde4/share/kde4/services/plasma-runner-bookmarks.desktop, but I guess Ubuntu uses .kde instead of .kde4)

Answer (score 2):

2020 solution (plasma 5.16.5): things related to system search are found in the system settings -> appearance -> plasma search. There are many interesting plugins here that influence what shows up in the search, including browser integration.

Answer (score 2):

New answer working with the UI in 2022 , just simply --> open settings --> Plasma Search --> Untick Browser History.

Problem solved, history is now disabled from Krunner (Alt+F2)  and start menu.