# Disable file search in KDE Kickoff Launcher

Tags: launcher, kde, search, kickoff

When I open Kickoff, there is the option to type-to-search for programs. However, the search results also list any files on the computer and also Firefox bookmarks.

I already succeeded to turn off the bookmark search [as described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/600645/184155), but I also want to disable searching for files. Basically I just want to have applications displayed that are listed somewhere in Kickoff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [posting](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=154&t=133235) the issue to the KDE forums, the solution was simply to do the same with the file `/usr/share/kservices5/plasma-runner-baloosearch.desktop`, i.e. copy to  to ~/.local/share/kservices5/ and set `X-KDE-PluginInfo-EnabledByDefault=false`